# Jquery handling submit button's click event without disrupting form post

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-events

I have a submit button and the following code that does something once its clicked:

```
<input name="Update" class="LongSubmit" id="Update" type="submit" WaitingValue="Updating..." value="Update"/>

        $('.LongSubmit').click(function() {
            $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            $(this).addClass('AjaxInProgress');
            $(this).val($('.LongSubmit').attr('WaitingValue'));
            $(this).closest('form').submit(); // Added so it submits the form
        })
```

I found that when I added this handler without the commented line the form didn't get submitted, so I added it in and now the form does get submitted.

However, if I click a submit button to click a form normally in the post there is the key `Update`, however when I do it programmatically within the click handler that key isn't there.

**How do I handle a submit button's click event without effecting the form's POST at all (i.e. having the `update` key there)?

(Or how can i emulate it exactly as if the handler wasn't there?)**

---

As Zefiryn has pointed out, it's because of disable the button, however I do want to do this to prevent multiple clicks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to solve this with Zefiryn's help, by disabling the button only after the form has been submitted:

```
    $(function() {

        $('.LongSubmit').click(function() {
            $(this).closest('form').submit();
            $(this).addClass('AjaxInProgress');
        })

        function DisableAjaxButtons() {
            $('.AjaxInProgress').val($('.AjaxInProgress').attr('WaitingValue'));
            $('.AjaxInProgress').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }

        $('form').submit(function() {
            setTimeout(DisableAjaxButtons, 1);
        })
    });
```

I'd still like to see if anyone has any ideas beyond this (IMO) some what hacky solution of creating a timer just so it happens after submission of the form.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't disable your submit button, you can use others techniques to block double submits. For example:

```
var submitFlag = 0;
$(function(){
    $('form').submit(function(){
        return submitFlag++ == 0;
    });
});
```

This will block any double submit of your forms. The flag will be reseted on page reload or postback (and if you use Ajax, you can extend this to reset this flag on ajax response too). Can this help you?

Answer (score 0):

The key update is from the update input. It is submit button but submit buttons are always send with POST so I do not know where is the problem. If you want to remove this field from POST you may change `<input>` to `<button>` (or any other tag) and add click handlers on them that will submit the form.

Comment: I *want* the `update` key sent. My problem is that it isn't when i programatically submit the form.

Comment: Maybe it is bacuse you set this input to disabled?

Comment: Just commented out that line and that is the case. I do want to disable it though, to prevent people clicking it multiple times, so I still have the same problem.

Comment: normally callling `.submit()` would cause standard submit and reload the page. I assume you have some custom logic in your submit handler. You may want to disable submit button there, after getting all data for post.

Comment: I'm using MVC with ASP.NET so the post gets passed to the framework to figure out what server method to run. The `Update` key is used to do this (as the form has multiple submit buttons).

Comment: I have no experience with ASP.NET. The question is where the request is actually being created and send. If it is ajax you may try move disabling button after `submit()` method.